# How to configure PostgreSQL 32bit ODBC?

Tags: postgresql, asp-classic, odbc

I am running a classic asp page and trying to connect to a postgresql database. I installed the 64 bit and was having issues - then realized need 32 bit because of asp. So did this from `ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/msi/…`

Now I'm getting

> "Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 5: Access is
>   denied"

when loading asp page. Went into manager `%SystemRoot%\syswow64\odbcad32.exe`, but when try to add new DSN, getting

> "The setup routines for the PostgreSQL Unicode ODBC Driver could not
>   be loaded due to a system error code 126: The specified module could
>   not be found. (C:\Program
>   Files(x86)\psqoODBC\0903\bil\psqlodbc35W.dll)".

Does anyone know of a good link for step by step setup of a 32 bit postgresql odbc driver because i am having so many issues.  Or has anyone else had these issues that might be able to lead me in the right direction?

Thanks so much,
Denise

Comment: Now I took care of the access denied error as I did not give access to the dll.  But I still keep getting the 126 error and have searched everywhere and don't know what to do.  I even re-installed the 32 bit driver.  And I also got rid of the 64 bit dsn's because I thought that was causing confusion.  Please please can someone help?  I am really stuck.  Thanks so much, Denise

Comment: I see that your system in in strange directory where some letters looks like a typo (`psqo` instead of `psql` or `bil` instead of `bin`). Please download new `psqlodbc_09_03_0300.zip` and install it. Write us what system do you use (Win7? Win8? other?) and if installation of ODBC driver was without errors.

Comment: Okay, I uninstalled and re-installed the whole psqlODBC (I think - did it from control panel).  Then re-started computer just in case.  And I can't add it in the manager.  Im using Windows 7 by the way and I get to the manager through %SystemRoot%\syswow64\odbcad32.exe.  I even checked the regedit again.  Its registry entry is in HK_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/ODBC/ODBCINST.INI, and here it says that the dll should be at C:\Program Files(x86)\psqlODBC\0903\bin\psqlodbc35W.dll, and it is there just like before.  So I really don't understand.  I think I'm going nuts

Comment: Oh, and sorry, the installation of the ODBC was without errors.

Comment: Well, guess what?  After much pain, but absolutely worth it, I've gotten it to work.  It turns out that some postgre is compiled in C++ and with Windows 2008, the C++ Redistributable is not installed by default.  So I installed this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29 - now I am able to configure the 32bit postgreSQL Unicode driver on my server, and of course I am also able to use it through my .asp page with connection string.
I really hope this helps, and thanks to all who looked into it.
Thanks again,
Denise

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue, saw your solution the comments and tried it to no avail, however I did keep searching and fixed it for my situation. It wasn't the 2008 redist but rather the [2010 x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) one for me.

Comment: Also worked for me with psqlodbc_09_03_0210 @ Windows Server 2012 x64.
Thanks!

Comment: @MateusBR I love you